# How to write customizer function for lodash _.mergeWith third argument in this situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, nested-object, customizer

I have two objects like that:

```
var obj3 = {
    customer_id: 1,
    products: { id: 1, name: "Car" },
  };

  var obj4 = {
    customer_id: 1,
    products: { id: 2, name: "Dress" },
  };
```

and the expected object is:

```
result = {
    customer_id: 1,
    products: [
      { id: 1, name: "Car" },
      { id: 2, name: "Dress" },
    ],
  };
```

How can i write `function customizer(){}` in this situation?
Thanks so much for your help, and i'll be welcome for other solution with different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the objects to a new object (the `{}`). Set the default values of the merged values to empty arrays. If the key is `products` concat them. If not return `undefined`, so the standard logic of `_.merge()` would be used:

```js
const obj3 = { customer_id: 1, products: { id: 1, name: "Car" }, };
const obj4 = { customer_id: 1, products: { id: 2, name: "Dress" }, };

const result = _.mergeWith({}, obj3, obj4, (v1 = [], v2 = [], key) =>
  key === 'products' ? v1.concat(v2) : undefined
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```